# Using arbitrarily named php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My objective is to extract each value of 3 columns of a SQL table. Although, I want to extract these values from different tables deppending on the value of listtype that is chosen. The columns Name and Reg_Date have the same name for all the tables. Although, the name of the column corresponding to ID may be either ID_Doctor, ID_Nurse or ID_Patient. How can I append $*POST['listtype'] to $ID* and be able to use it inside an echo?
Below is the code that I tried, although the echo always returns the string ID_Doctor, ID_Nurse, or ID_Patient, deppending on the value of $_POST['listtype'].

```
$ID = '$ID_' .$_POST['listtype'];

while($count < $pages_c)
{
  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
  { 
    extract($rows); 
    $numrows++;
    echo "<tr><td>$ID</td><td>$Name</td><td>$Reg_Date</td></tr>";
  }
$count++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to accomplish that.

```
echo "<tr><td>${$ID}</td><td>$Name</td><td>$Reg_Date</td></tr>";
```

Keep in mind that you do not need to use `extract` to get the values from your `$rows` array. You could read them directly using `$rows['key']` syntax.

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{ 
    $numrows++;
    echo "<tr><td>{$rows[$ID]}</td><td>{$rows['Name']}</td><td>{$rows['Reg_Date']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Side note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and will be removed in the future. I'd recommend you to stick with [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr><td>",$rows[$ID],"</td><td>$Name</td><td>$Reg_Date</td></tr>";
```